# How can I add new keys to a keyring without hurting my fingernails?

Tags: home

Adding new keys to a keyring is a fiddly job - you have to prise apart the parts of the ring and hold it open long enough to get the new key on.

My current method is to pull it apart with my nails wide enough to push the key in flat, then I lever the key upwards to get it in the rest of the way.

This kind of hurts my nails. Is there a better way of doing it? I saw some suggestions online to use a staple remover, but that's not something I've ever owned or had a need for, so I don't want to buy one specially.

Comment: @Zach I explicitly say I don't want to use a staple remover.

Comment: Even if one of the answers is unacceptable, the question is the same

Comment: @starsplusplus The other question has other answers besides a staple remover.

Comment: @Zach One of the answers is what I do already, one of the answers is something I don't own, and the third has two suggestions - one of which I don't own, and the other which is no better than what I do already. Questions should be closed as duplicates on StackExchange iff they can be answered by the answers on another question. Which of those answers supposedly answers my question? I don't think any of them do, for the reasons I just gave.

Comment: @starsplusplus If you feel a question doesn't have enough attention, you're welcome to start a bounty on the question. You can even put a custom reason explaining your reason for wanting new answers. Asking a duplicate question with certain answers disallowed is not the correct thing to do

Comment: @Zach technically, if the current answers do not solve your problem, they can ask another and explain why they don't solve it...

Comment: @Tim I stand by my comment. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: @Zach Yes, but he is entitled to ask a new question if the old one is not satisfactory. Look at the marked as duplicate banner - "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. **If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question**."